# How to use PHP in Javascript

Tags: php, jquery, database

This is the jquery that i'm using.

I need to use the returned data and store it in a db usin php.

```
'onComplete'  : function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {

      alert('Your video has been uploaded. Thanks.');
```

Now inside this, i want to use the retuned fileOBJ and store it. How do i do that?

Comment: Please provide more context. Where is this callback being called from and after what kind of action?

Comment: You need to send the data via AJAX to a PHP script.

Answer (score 4):

You could place an AJAX call inside of the function that submits the data to the php page.

```
'onComplete'  : function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {

  alert('Your video has been uploaded. Thanks.');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'your_php_page.php',
        data: fileOBJ,
        success: function(msg) {
           //do something
        },
        error: function(msg) {
           //handle error
        }
    });
}
```

Then you'd simply create a php page that would submit the posted data to your database.

Read more about the `$.ajax()` call [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Answer (score 3):

This technique is usually referred to as "Ajax" these days.  The scope of your question is too broad to answer here, I recommend you do some reading on it.